# create a new laravel logging channel through ServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, logging

I am in the process of creating a Laravel package. Is it possible to create new logging channels through a ServiceProvider class?

I have manually created a new logging channel in my `config/logging.php`, however I would prefer if the package could do this automatically for me in the future.

**Update**:
I have a Laravel package in which will use it's own logging stack and file. Here is the code I have in my `config/logging.php` right now:

```
'deployment' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/deployment.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
],
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you say logging channels do you mean a separate log file? Or do you mean like `info` and `debug`?

Comment: @thisiskelvin: Yes. In `config/logging.php` you can define new channels in which will output to a different file (if that is the desired action).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `app('log')` to get the LogManager singleton from the service container and the `public function stack(array $channels, $channel=null)` method to pass in an array of channels you want to add.

```
app('log')->stack([
    'channels' => [
        'test' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/test.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 30,
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I *already have* added my log configuration in the `config/logging.php` file. I am looking to do this programmatically.

Comment: Updated the answer to address adding additional logger configurations at runtime.  I'm not sure why you'd want to add configurations at runtime though... or how you'd know which channel to use when creating a log. There may be a different solution to your problem if you share the reason behind what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my question. Your answer seems like it would work however I haven't tested it yet. Thanks for providing your answer.

Comment: Ok. It actually sounds like you just want users to be able to install your own pre-defined configuration.  This is done through publishing. More here (with the config example): https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#publishing-file-groups

Comment: @zyglobe the documentation you referenced don't answer the question, since having a custom package publishing its own files WILL NOT add a new entry into an already existing config file, i.e. `config/logging.php`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
$this->app->make('config')->set('logging.channels.deployment', [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/deployment.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
]);
```

in your `ServiceProvider::boot` method

Comment: I can confirm this works in Laravel 10. Great!